# How set auto focus next in input type time

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a simple input with type of `time` and I try to set auto focus next input in the DOM tree

```
<input type="time" name="startTime" (keyup)="setFocus($event)"/>

setFocus(element) {
    if (element.target.value.length == 5) {

        let coll = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        let array = Array.from(coll)
        let thisOne = array.forEach((el) => {
            if (el == element.target) {
                let index = array.indexOf(el)

                let next = array[index + 1]

                next.focus();
                next.select();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

The problem is when the time had default value the value length is always 5 (on keyup) like `05:45` or `18:22`, so how could I set next auto focus? Is there any way to find out the cursor is in the 5th position? any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "next input"? The next `input` in the DOM tree of your "time input" ?

Comment: please show all relevant sections of your code for better understanding

Comment: Question Updated

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you have id for the input element, then you can set focus with JavaScript focus method like this

```
document.getElementById(next.id).focus();
```

**Edit:** I found that focus doesn't work if element don't have id, if you set your element id, then your code will perfectly work.

Comment: The problem is not how focus, is about when to focus